# Why is the *ExpiredJwtException* not being caught and handled?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jwt

Why is the *ExpiredJwtException* not being caught and handled?

When I pass an expired token into the validate endpoint, a *ExpiredJwtException* is thrown but it is not being handled is the catch block:

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> validateToken(@RequestParam String token,
                                           @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        try {
            Boolean isValidToken = jwtUtility.validateToken(token, user);
            System.out.println("Is valid" + isValidToken);
            ValidateResponse res = new ValidateResponse();
            res.setIsValid(isValidToken);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(res);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            ValidateResponse res = new ValidateResponse();
            res.setIsValid(false);
            System.out.println("Is valid" + res);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(res);
        }
    }
```

In JWTUtility.java:

```
//validate token
public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}


//check if the token has expired
private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
    return expiration.before(new Date());
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <!-- JWT Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Stack Trace:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2022-07-20T14:25:56Z. Current time: 2022-07-20T14:25:56Z, a difference of 261 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:448) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:550) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:610) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
    at com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.util.JWTUtility.getAllClaimsFromToken(JWTUtility.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.util.JWTUtility.getClaimFromToken(JWTUtility.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.util.JWTUtility.getUsernameFromToken(JWTUtility.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.filter.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Include your stacktrace that shows this.

Comment: Check the parent exception which is wrapping your `ExpiredJwtException` , Handle that exception in `exceptionhandler`

Comment: Also let us know about this `jwtUtility.validateToken(token, user)`  `jwtUtility class` and `validatetoken` method? is it some library or your own implemented class.

Comment: Methods added. You can also check out the full codebase here: https://github.com/clancinio/assignment-submission-backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gone through your [Github Link](https://github.com/clancinio/assignment-submission-backend/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/assignmentsubmissionapp/filter/JwtFilter.java) codebase as per my analysis you should do below things.

Change your `JwtFilter` class, the exception which is getting thrown from the `io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts` class is getting suppressed because of your catch block.

you should stop the further execution and return if you get any exception.

```
catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
```

to below

```
catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, Rishal! It's really helpful, though I'd prefer catching and handling *all* exceptions in that way, rather than just the ExpiredJwtException.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace shows the exception is coming from different code path.

From the stack trace:

com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.filter.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:36)
is calling
com.example.assignmentsubmissionapp.util.JWTUtility.getUsernameFromToken(JWTUtility.java:29)

which is throwing the exception, so it is thrown in JwtFilter. The catch block you have is in validateToken(), which is nowhere to be seen in the stack trace.

So based on the stack trace the exception is thrown before validateToken() method is ever called. If you want to catch the exception you'd need to do it in JwtFilter.

Answer (score 0):

From what I searched, the only method that throws a `ExpiredJwtException` is the `parse(String jwt) throws ExpiredJwtException, ...` method, probably you are not calling the method that will throw it. If you are using jjwt of course.